# Expansion and simplification of the Euler-Lagrange equation for $g = \sqrt{1+\dot{x}^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

According to my solutions guide, if I am given:

$$g = \sqrt{1+\dot{x}^2}$$

where $\dot{x}$ is a function of time, then the following equation:

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial  x} - \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \frac{\partial g}{\partial \dot{x}} \right] = 0$$

should simplify to:

$$\ddot{x} = 0$$

but that is not what I'm getting...here are my steps

I ignore the left term since g is not a function of x, and the inner partial becomes:

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial \dot{x}} = \frac{\dot{x}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+1}}$$

Taking the time derivative calls for the quotient rule:

$$\frac{\dot{f}p - f\dot{p}}{p^2}$$

where $f = \dot{x}, \dot{f} = \ddot{x}, p = \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+1}$

I use the chain rule to find $\dot{p}$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{x}}\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+1}\frac{\partial \dot{x}}{\partial t} = \frac{\ddot{x}\dot{x}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+1}}$$

My quotient rule becomes:

$$\frac{\ddot{x}\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+1}-\ddot{x}\dot{x}^2\ (\dot{x}^2+1)^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{\dot{x}^2+1}$$

which is not reducing to $\ddot{x}$. Did I make a mistake or is my solutions guide mistaken?

Comment: If you are putting an equation on its own line, use display math `$$...$$`

Answer (score 1):

Note that the mess you derived is set equal to zero. Pull out the $\ddot{x}$ and you get:

$\ddot{x}\frac{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+1}-\dot{x}^2\ (\dot{x}^2+1)^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{\dot{x}^2+1}=0$

Now, note that all the terms in the second factor are *squared*, so $\frac{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+1}-\dot{x}^2\ (\dot{x}^2+1)^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{\dot{x}^2+1}\neq 0\;\;\forall x$

Therefore, the only way to make the equality work out is if $\ddot{x}=0$